# Como multiplicar todos os valores dentro de uma lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um programa que recebe uma lista de bases e expoentes. Assim, realiza a potenciação entre eles e, logo após, multiplica os resultados. Contudo, estou com dubiedades em relação a multiplicação dos resultados. Até o momento, fui capaz de desenvolver isso:

```
def potenciacao(Bases,Expoentes):
    #Recebendo as Bases e Expoentes, ambas armazenadas em listas e possuem o mesmo tamanho
    resultados = [Bases[i]**Expoentes[i] for i in range(len(Bases))]
    # Realizando a potenciação entre eles com um list comprehension
    Resultado = map(lambda x,y = x*y,resultados)
    # Pensei em utilizar a função map do python para realizar isso, mas não consegui 
    return Resultado
```

Existe alguma função no python que realize esse tipo de operação com listas? Ou algum método?

Comment: Você precisa multiplicar os resultados? Não seria somá-los? Aliás, a `map` não faz o que deseja, provavelmente é a `reduce` que você precisa.

Comment: Sim, preciso multiplicar os valores contidos na lista 'resultados'.

Comment: Desde já agradeço, a partir da função `reduce` consegui realizar o que necessitava